# Can I Run iAd as well as AdMob Parallel Or Alternate In Only One Application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, admob, iad

I Want iAd And AdMob In My Application 
    Is it possible to provide  Add By Both Of This way in My One application ?
   Or I Want Alternate Add From this Both Add Network  what Are the Possibilities for to give the Add  By BOth WAy ?

Thank You In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adwhirl is great for doing this. Check it out: https://www.adwhirl.com/home/dev

Or when you want to do some crazy stuff you could even use a random number do decide which adview is shown, either iAd or AdMob ^^

Answer (score 3):

Use these controls to add iAd as well as adMob both,

```
https://github.com/pjcook/iAdPlusAdMob

https://github.com/chrisjp/CJPAdController
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like AdWhirl to control multiple ad networks. That way you can allocate percentage of fill to each network.

Please note AdWhirl is not bad but we've had lots of problems/crashes when integrating it which we've had to sort out ourselves.

There are other similar tools but I ve not tried them.